# SqlNullValueException when i use userManager.AddToRoleAsync method

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I use identity in **core2.2** and in my register action in contorller I want get a rol **"User"** to new member but when use `var`

```
result1 = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
```

this get `SqlNullValueException` 
please help me

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(int i)
 this is stack trace

Comment: Please upload full code of user entity. It's really to tell when you just give us 1 line of code